# Sql lower changes selected string encoding

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

When selecting a column as `lower` its output type is changed to `bytes` and I wonder why and how to select consistently if needed to compare with `unicode` after.

```
result = connection.execute("select lower(email) as email, order_id, box from in_emails_boxes")
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

Yields:

```
(b'lyd*****@orange.fr', 136976, 'BOXMOIS')
```

Comment: Which mysql driver are you using?

Comment: I think it's `mysqldb`